# Как создать запрос для связи many-to-many

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть таблица `Word`

```
id (int)
word (text)
```

Есть таблица `PartsOfSpeech`

```
id (int)
name (text)
```

Связал связанную таблицу `Combinations`. Занёс данные

```
id (int)
word_id (int)
ps_id (int)
```

Теперь стоит задача вывести все в единую таблицу. Пробовал через `Union`, но оно просто в столбик все данные вводит. А мне нужно чтобы было Word | PartsOfSpeech

```
SELECT p.*  FROM word p
union 
select ps.* from partsOfSpeech ps
```

Comment: Не очень понятно какой именно вы хотите результат. Добавьте пример того вывода, который вам нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется вывести все введенные пары, то это обычное связывание таблиц

```
select
  с.id,
  w.name word,
  ps.name PartsOfSpeech
from Combinations c,
     PartsOfSpeech ps,
     word w
where c.word_id = w.id
and   c.ps_id = ps.id
```

Если требуется все варианты для слова, то

```
select
  w.id,
  w.name word,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name,'; ') PartsOfSpeechs
from Combinations c,
     PartsOfSpeech ps,
     word w
where c.word_id = w.id
and   c.ps_id = ps.id 
group by w.name
```

Если не для всех слов есть записи в `Combinations`, а слова надо вывести все, то необходимо использовать`LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: в sqlite вроде left join не работает

Comment: Я погуглил, поддержка есть.